# Dictionary contains duplicate keys , automated fix help needed

Tags: python

I have created a 10k lines dictionary for a program I am making, some of the entries has duplicate keys because of the way the data need to be presented.
The fix for this is to turn the "value" into a list, removing duplicate keys.
I was wondering if there is an automated way to do this? (PyCharm)

For example:

```
dict = {
"A": "Red",
"A": "Blue",
"A": "Green",
"B": "Yellow",
"C": "Black"
}
```

wanted output :

```
dict = {
"A": ["Red","Blue","Green"],
"B": "Yellow",
"C": "Black"
}
```

I've tried ChatGPT and manual labor :D
Looking for a smarter way to do this and learning new ways.

Comment: The first dict, you have shared is not possible. Dicts **MUST** have unique keys, in this case modified dict will be `{'A': 'Green', 'B': 'Yellow', 'C': 'Black'}`, but I can get your problem statement. Please share your code logic and including source of the data.

Comment: `
>>> original_dict = {"A": "Red", "A": "Blue", "A": "Green", "B": "Yellow", "C": "Black"}
>>> original_dict
{'A': 'Green', 'B': 'Yellow', 'C': 'Black'}
`

Comment: you should give us your code and then we can help you

Comment: Maybe a dictionary is not the best collection type for your application. But without more details it is difficult to suggest something better.

Comment: If you enter a dictionary that contains duplicate keys, the earlier keys will be dropped. This said, a dictionary is not the right type to use. But you can enter the data for example as  (key, value) tuples and construct a dictionary later.

Comment: Your scenario is impossible to begin with

Comment: Your "wanted output" would be horribly inconvenient to use - every single time you access data from this dict, you'd have to have separate code to handle the single value and multiple value cases.  It would be far better to *always* use a list to hold the values, even if there's only one.

Comment: Where does that broken dictionary come from? Can you fix the program that generates it? If not, you could try to parse the Python source code and convert it to the wanted structure.

Comment: Item by item in the original string insert them into a Collectios.defaultdict(list)

Answer (score 3):

In a dictionary in Python, if you have items with the same keys, they just get overwritten by further items, so in your dict finally you could only have 1 item with the key "A".

My suggestion to you is to try to get all that in a single expression, and simply parse that, so 1 item is key, next is data, next is key and so on.

You can do that simply by replacing ":" with ",", as I did in the following code

```
array = ("A", "Red", "A", "Blue", "A", "Green", "B", "Yellow", "C", "Black", "B", "smth")


def parse_dictionary(array):
    dictionary = {}
    for item_key, item in zip(array[::2], array[1::2]):
        if item_key in dictionary:
            if type(dictionary[item_key]) == list:
                dictionary[item_key].append(item)
            else:
                a = dictionary[item_key]
                dictionary[item_key] = [a, item]
        else:
            dictionary[item_key] = item
    return dictionary
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think dict is a good datatype for you. I can suggest you to use a list of tuples.

```
list_of_tuples = [("A", "Red"), ("A", "Blue"), ("A", "Green"), ("B", "Yellow"), ..]
```

If you have duplicate keys, the earlier keys will be overwritten by the later ones.

I am assuming that you have stored your data in a txt file, here is my suggestion:

To convert your "dict" to the `list_of_tuples` , you can convert it first into a list.

```
sample_list = ["A", "Red", "A", "Blue", "A", "Green", "B", "Yellow", ..]
```

That would be easier by doing a find and replace for the `:` symbol and replace it with `,` symbol in the file where you are storing your 10k lines of "dict", and replacing the end curly braces (`{}`) with square ones (`[]`).

Then you can convert it into the list of tuples

```
a = iter(sample_list)
list_of_tuples = list(zip(a, a))
# Output will be: list_of_tuples = [("A", "Red"), (A", "Blue"), ("A", "Green"),
```

Answer (score 0):

Python dictionaries **DO NOT ALLOW** duplicate keys, for instance, the following line will be evaluated like this

```
>>> d = {"a": 2, "a": 3, "b": 4}
>>> print(d)
{'a': 3, 'b': 4}
```

I don't have any idea how you could generate such a dict in a Python, maybe if you provided your raw data format we could come up with a solution.

Supposed you have a string, you can do something like this

```
j = '{"A": "Red", "A": "Blue", "A": "Green", "B": "Yellow", "C": "Black"}'

# Remove the surrounding curly braces from the string
j = j[1:-1]

# Split the string into key-value pairs
pairs = [pair.strip().replace('"', '') for pair in j.split(',')]

new_dict = {}

# Loop through the extracted key-value pairs
for pair in pairs:
    key, value = pair.split(':')
    key = key.strip()
    value = value.strip().strip('"')

    if key not in new_dict:
        new_dict[key] = value  # If key is not already in new_dict, create a list with the value
    else:
        if type(new_dict[key]) != list:
            new_dict[key] = [new_dict[key]]
        new_dict[key].append(value)  # If key already exists, append the value to the list

# Print the transformed dictionary
print(new_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Initially format `dict` into `str` by adding triple quotes before and after.
2. Format further by removing curly braces, double quotes etc. This you can do programmatically

   ```
   txt = '''{"A": "Red",
   "A": "Blue",
   "A": "Green",
   "B": "Yellow",
   "C": "Black"
   }
   '''

   txt = txt.replace('{', '').replace('}', '').replace('"', '')
   ls = txt.split(',\n')

   new_dct = {}
   for x in ls:
       idx = x.find(':')
       key = x[:idx].strip()
       value = x[idx+1:].strip()
       if key not in new_dct.keys():
           new_dct[key] = [value]
       else:
           new_dct[key].append(value)

   # Optional: if there is single element in value make the value as string

   for k, v in new_dct.items():
       if len(v) == 1:
           new_dct[k] = v[0]

   print(new_dct) #Output : {'A': ['Red', 'Blue', 'Green'], 'B': 'Yellow', 'C': 'Black'}
   ```